# Two different child process not generating unique number

Tags: python

Why two unique child process not generating unique random number?

```
import os
import string
import random

def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
  print ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size)).lower()
  os._exit(0)

for i in range(2):
  newpid = os.fork()
  if newpid == 0:
     id_generator()
  else:
    print "Parent"
```

Output is showing same random number:

```
Parent
Parent
q52mno
q52mno
```

Comment: Because you haven't seeded the random number generator differently in the two processes.

Comment: Note: If you used `multiprocessing` to spawn worker processes instead of the low-level `os.fork` primitive, it actually does reseed the Python PRNG for you, so you wouldn't generate the same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import the `random` module, it gives the RNG a default seed. Then when you fork, the child process inherits this seed. So both child processes are starting with the same default seed.

You need to call `random.seed()` in each process with different arguments, perhaps add the PID to the time.

```
for i in range(2):
  newpid = os.fork()
  if newpid == 0:
     random.seed(os.pid() + time.time())
     id_generator()
  else:
    print "Parent"
```

If you know your Python implementation uses the operating system's good source of randomness, you could just call:

```
random.seed()
```

with no arguments in each process.

Comment: Its not even that they are fast, since this is a fork, it was only seeded once. You likely don't need to pass anything to seed, it does a good job on its own.

Comment: @tdelaney I assumed it doesn't generate a default seed until the first time you call one of the functions, so each process is seeding it the same. But if the initial seed is done when the module is imported, then indeed they're just using the same seed.

Comment: Yeah, `random` creates a `random.Random` object on import and uses its methods as `random.choice` and etc.... I think its done even before random officially imports as part of the base python runtime, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: For the record, don't pass your own seed, particularly terrible ones like the PID or the time. When `seed` is called without arguments, Python seeds from an OS provided source of cryptographically secure random numbers, e.g. `/dev/urandom` on *NIX or `CryptGenRandom` on Windows, which is a much better seed value than any quasi-random thing you'd come up with yourself.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The documentation says it could use the time. If we seed from the time, it will likely be the same in both processes. That's why I added something unique to each process.

Comment: @Barmar: Downside: It means if there are better OS sources of randomness (the case on every major non-embedded OS Python currently ships on to my knowledge), you just overwrote them with a fairly terrible seed value (the PID may make the stream unique per process, but it's extremely limited entropy). If you really worry about time based seeding, make the `seed` call something like `random.seed(os.pid() + time.time() + random.getrandbits(48))`. If the reseed was good, that preserves the goodness. If the reseed was garbage because you're on the one OS w/o OS randomness, the PID helps a bit.

Comment: Choice of `getrandbits(48)` was to avoid overflowing `float` (`C` `double`) representation limits once time is added on. In practice, probably best to multiply out and convert `time` to `int` to allow more complete seeds, but anything is better than just `pid` + `time`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger OK, I've added more to my answer, suggesting calling it with no arguments if you know the implementation uses a good source of randomness.

Comment: Thanks @Barmer and all for your help

Comment: @CoderTag SO does name completion after `@` so there's no excuse for misspelling my name.

Answer (score 0):

Python’s `random` module is a **pseudorandom** number generator; to get different output, you need to perturb the **seed** to something different.

```
random.seed()
```

[By default](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) python uses either the system time as the seed, or some hardware randomizer provided by the OS (get this explicitly from [`os.urandom()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom) if it is available). Often, this is enough, but in some cases, like this, where both processes have the same system time, you need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

When a python process generates a "random" number it's really using a deterministic algorithm. That algorithm has a bunch of properties that make it look like it's generating random numbers. The first value that it uses is called the seed value, and it's really important because each subsequent value is generated from the previous output value. You're running the exact same process, so you're using the same seed value both times. And therefore will generate the same sequence of values.

If you want the two processes to return different sequences you could try seeding the algorithm with the pid, for example.